# Google Chrome, GDI++, and --no-sandbox

Tags: google-chrome, security, fonts, sandbox

I use Google Chrome as the most preferrable web browser, and I'm also a fan of GDI++ (but not gdipp) tool that allows to replace the system font renderer to a *MacOS-like one*. That tool is able to affect the font rendering almost in all applications except of some system controls (like menus) as well as Chrome. I've found that the `--no-sandbox` switch in Chrome allows to reach the text appearance I really love and prefer, but it's a possible security threat. If not using the switch, GDI++ has no effect at all...

Is there a way to launch Chrome without `--no-sandbox` but considering GDI++ as a trusted application somehow (I'm not sure, GDI++ might try to inject some code)? Or should I pay attention at gdipp?

Thanks in advance.

Little P.S. I prefer GDI++ rather than gdipp, because GDI++ is more configurable to render fonts the way I like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://d.hatena.ne.jp/kf1984/20100205/1265390981, GDI++ Helium supports non-single-process Chrome, not sure since when but the version mentioned is 2008-12-25.
Maybe you can try the Beginner's Starter Pack, downloadable at http://free.flop.jp/gdi++/ (gdi0959.zip)

By the way, in what way do you need to configure gdi++ that is not achievable in gdipp?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, syockit. Perhaps, I incorrectly said, but I could not configure gdipp the same way I did it for GDI++: well, being honestly, as far as I remember, gdipp just uses another options, and that confused me. :) I can show you a screenshot that reflects my current and favorite GDI++ settings (I don't know how to reach them exactly in gdipp): http://i18.fastpic.ru/big/2011/0324/ad/bf9d6f130f84ce83c9efe78a8d44ffad.png . Perhaps you know, is it possible to get the exact style using gdipp? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the related gdi++.ini entries on your question? The freetype edition has it under [Freetype], the Helium edition may have it under [Rasterize] and [Misc] as well, while the original edition probably has everything under [General].

Comment: Here's my GDI++ config: http://andem.freehostia.com/gdi++.ini

Comment: gdipp 0.9.1 has some unresolved font metrics bugs, so I'm unable to imitate your style with success. Your style uses embolden, but if I enable that, some letters have their last 2 pixel widths cut off. Maybe you should use Helium, available at the link I gave earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, syockit. I'll try and take your advices into account.